# Selecting Random Record and Marking Record As Being Used

Tags: sql, ms-access, random, vba, ms-access-2007

So, the following selects a random team to be used. Once selected, I mark this team being as used as an X in the Used field with a update query later on. For the most it works, but after running this a handful of times, I start to get duplicated teams, even with them being marked as X.

What else am I missing to accomplish this?

Here is the SQL statement:

```
SELECT TOP 1 RandomTeams.[Team Name], RandomTeams.Used
FROM RandomTeams
WHERE (((RandomTeams.Used) Is Null))
ORDER BY Rnd(TeamID);
```

Here's how I'm handling the updates to mark a team as being used, which is working as expected, I have no issues here when marking with an X:

Text214.Text contains the team name that is being used

```
strTeam = (Chr(34) + Text214.Text + (Chr(34)))

strSQLUpdateTeams = "UPDATE RandomTeams SET Used = 'X' WHERE [Team Name] = " & strTeam

DoCmd.SetWarnings (WarningsOff)
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQLUpdateTeams
```

Comment: Do you have duplicates in the `RandomTeams` table?  If you are setting `Used` to `'X'` in the same table, then this query will not return those values.

Comment: Is your program a single thread/process, or can there be several such queries running in parallel?

Comment: @GordonLinoff No duplicate teams, checked that a couple times, all unique

Comment: @Mureinik Single thread, I run each query separate via VBA, one for selecting the random team and one for marking the team as being used. I'll eventually run all together once I figure out why duplicate teams keep popping up.

Comment: I just tried this using your SQL and it worked fine - eventually returning no record.. That leads me to ask how/when you set the 'Used' flag? In my case, I had 10 teams, and each time I ran the query, I manually placed an X in the Used field.

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn I updated my original question. FYI, I have no issues with how a team is being marked as being used (X). This is working as expected though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a test, how about just throwing the following code into a module, then execute it and see what happens. BTW, how are you resetting [Used]?

```
    Sub Test_Teams()
    Dim strSQL      As String
    Dim strTeam     As String
    Dim strSQLUpdateTeams   As String
    Dim dbs         As DAO.Database
    Dim rs          As DAO.recordSet

    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    If MsgBox("Do you want to reset all 'Used' flags?", vbYesNo, "Reset?") = vbYes Then
        strSQL = "update RandomTeams set [Used] = null;"
        dbs.Execute strSQL

    End If
MyLoop:
    strSQL = "SELECT TOP 1 RandomTeams.[Team Name], RandomTeams.Used " & _
            "FROM RandomTeams " & _
            "WHERE (((RandomTeams.Used) Is Null)) " & _
            "ORDER BY Rnd(TeamID);"

    Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    If Not rs.EOF Then
        strTeam = rs![Team Name]
        Debug.Print "Found Team: " & strTeam
    Else
        MsgBox "EOF! No more teams."
        rs.Close
        Set rs = Nothing
        dbs.Close
        Set dbs = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End If
    strTeam = (Chr(34) + rs![Team Name] + (Chr(34)))
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

    strSQLUpdateTeams = "UPDATE RandomTeams SET [Used] = 'X' WHERE [Team Name] = " & strTeam
    Debug.Print strSQLUpdateTeams
    'DoCmd.SetWarnings (WarningsOff)
    'DoCmd.RunSQL strSQLUpdateTeams
    dbs.Execute strSQLUpdateTeams
    If dbs.RecordsAffected <> 1 Then
        MsgBox "Whoa! Not good! Update failed!"
    End If
    GoTo MyLoop


End Sub
```

Comment: I have a query to count the number of X's. If equal to total amount of teams, in this case total teams is 30, run an update query to fill the field with null values.

Comment: Ok, I tried this and it looped through the entire table and marked each team as being used with an X.

Comment: Since my code worked by selecting a random team, then marking as USED, there must be some other code or interface that is preventing yours from working. Single user? 'Used' defined as type of 'Text'? If your code is in a form, you could count the teams when the form opens, then after every select or setting 'Used', count the records again and if a difference, halt the code so you can examine what happened between the two selections. Do the 'duplicated teams' actually exist in the table, or are they just returned from your query?

Comment: Yeah single user, all queries, etc controlled on a form, via command buttons. So the results from your code is what you expected huh? Alright I guess its back to square one.

Comment: All my code does is randomly select a record as step 1, then set that flag to 'used' as part 2. I've run it a number of times and it has not failed yet, so there must be something in either your code or your processing flow that is causing the duplicates.